# How to stack 3 button with different sizes (swift / iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, button

My question is how to stack three buttons in horizontal stack view. Two buttons have same size but one button has different size (see the screenshot) 
[image: img]

Button number 1 and 3 have same size but button number 2 have smaller size.
I tried to do it but this is my result, all three buttons have same size :(
[image: my result]

Answer (score 3):

Stack Views to the rescue!

Create a horizontal stack view to contain your 3 buttons.
Put positioning constraints on the stack view itself.
Put width constraints on the buttons that need it.
I chose to set the width for the outside buttons so that the inside button fills the remaining space.
Image below with the important parts circled.

[image: Stack View Setup]

Comment: It appears this creates buttons of the same size. I believe the question wanted buttons of different sizes.

Comment: All buttons will be in the same size and I don't want that

Comment: Yep, you're correct, will try to update my answer soon

Answer (score 1):

You could set the middle button with a constant constraint and center align it, then set the two outer buttons to have the equal widths (there is a constraint specifically for this) and constrain them to the middle button and the edge of the view.

Comment: If the middle button's center-aligned, you shouldn't need to set the other two to equal widths

Comment: Do you mean that I don't need to make a stack to my buttons?

Comment: Nope, just put them in a normal view

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and comment

Comment: [img](http://s7.postimg.org/pj37zxeyz/Simulator_Screen_Shot_Mar_4_2016_7_28_50_AM.png). and [img](http://s7.postimg.org/ekryhqqdn/Simulator_Screen_Shot_Mar_4_2016_7_29_11_AM.png).

Comment: The first img looks a lot like your goal, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, but if I rotate the iphone or change it to ipad I have this problem

Comment: It looks like you have the constraints set to opposite of what you need.  The center one needs to have a fixed width and the two on the side should be flexible